# Referenced Error in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

In my app, i made a `Core.h` file & declare some methods. In other files, i import `core.h', make a object of it and call methods through object still it does not show me any error.

But When try to run my app,
It shows error Like:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Core", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in ReadingDatabaseAppDelegate.o
  objc-class-ref in HomeController.o
```

My code:

```
// HomeController.h

#import "Core.h"


//HomeController.m

- (void)startInitialising:(id)sender
{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    

    //NSLog(@"%@ %@", [UIDevice currentDevice].systemName, [UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion);

    Core *coreObj = [[Core alloc] init];
    threadArray = [coreObj getPreferences];
    threadPrefereneRow = [coreObj getSavedPreferene];
    threadLastUpdated = [coreObj getSavedRequestTime];
    threadNumberOfUpdates = [coreObj getNumberOfUpdates:threadLastUpdated];
    [coreObj release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FinishInitializing object:nil];
    [pool release];
}


-(void) finishInitializingHandler: (NSNotification *) sender
{
Core *coreObj = [[Core alloc] init];
    [coreObj setTabbarSyncValue:tabBar];
    [coreObj release];
}
```

**How can i solve this**

Comment: Inherit that class where you want used like @core & check...

Comment: In place of core you add class name that you want to use in another class...

Comment: Did you copy that Core.h file from any other project to this project??

Comment: is Core.h just a "`.h`" file, or is there a "`.m`" implementation file to go with it?  Can you edit your question to show how you are calling "`Core`" from HomeController.m and ReadingDatabaseAppDelegate.m?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann i have only `core.h` file, there is no .m file. I Just import core.h in HomeController & other files.

Comment: edit your question to show how you are calling into the Core.h file from the code in HomeController and/or ReadingDatabaseAppDelegate.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I edited my question with some code. In core.h file,i just declare the methods without any implementation.

Comment: what does your Core.h file look like?  Usually if you have a interface defined in a "`.h`", you need an "`.m`" implementation as well.

Comment: can i post some code from `core.h` file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A header file by itself isnt enough. You need the matching implementation file (either as .m file, a .a library, a dylib or a framework.

---

simplified:

think of .h files as a bookmark to webpages
(they contain a link and a description but no actual content)